# Angular-material-table :- Getting error for mat-table

Tags: angular

below code is giving me eror. if I comment below code I am not getting error. I am  following proper format even then getting error.
I am also pasting ts code. Although I feel error is because of HTML.

```
<mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="preserve-whitespace">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                  <mat-header-cell title="ID" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><span class="sort-button-label">ID</span></mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell data-label="ID" *matCellDef="let element"><span title="{{element.id}}">{{element.id}}</span></mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
    </mat-table>
```

Error is

```
Problem occured in the UI:  Error: Missing definitions for header, footer, and row; cannot determine which columns should be rendered.
    at getTableMissingRowDefsError (main.4cd61bb9c267853d266e.js:25156)
    at MatTable.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkTable.ngAfterContentChecked (main.4cd61bb9c267853d266e.js:25956)
    at callProviderLifecycles (main.4cd61bb9c267853d266e.js:87729)
```

Ts code

```
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  displayedColumns = [
    'id',
    'projectName',
    'lastUpdated'
  ];

ngOnInit() {
    const data: PlatformChangeSummaryItem[] = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      const status = Math.floor(i % 5);
      if (i % 5 === 0) {
        data.push({

          id: 'PR123456',
          projectName: 'test123',
          lastUpdated: '10/12/12@12:10AM',
          filterMap: null,
          filterableProps: this.displayedColumns

        });
     }
    }
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PlatformChangeSummaryItem>(data);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.filterContent.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    this.cd.markForCheck();
    this.filterContent.dataSourceObservable.subscribe(dataSource => {
      this.dataSource = dataSource;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Paste your .ts code as well

Comment: I did..............................

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if answer help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `mat-row` and `mat-header-row`(optional) tags inside your table:

```html
<mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="preserve-whitespace">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
                         <mat-header-cell title="ID" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><span class="sort-button-label">ID</span></mat-header-cell>

                    </mat-header-row>
                  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
                      <mat-cell data-label="ID" *matCellDef="let element"><span title="{{element.id}}">{{element.id}}</span></mat-cell>
                  </mat-row>

                </ng-container>
    </mat-table>
```